# Regex string commas,characters

Tags: python, regex

Hey guys I dont usually use regex so I need a bit of help to get some matches from the below string. I only want the information in bold to match the regex expression, any help or explanation would be appreciated thanks.

'"FM 2222 RD / RIVER PLACE BLVD","0:",,"18:","00","**2008-08-14**","**CRASH/LEAVING THE SCENE**","30.39452568","(30.39452568-97.84551164)","-97.84551164","18:00:00","4","2008-08-14 18:00:00-06:00","20085043619"'

Comment: This looks like a line from a csv file, do you have to use regex?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about your criteria, because the regex `"2008-08-14","CRASH/LEAVING THE SCENE"` fits your description

Comment: SO is not a coding service.  Tell us what you've tried so far.  Play around in https://regex101.com and see if you can get a starting point

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is to detect the date and the field next to it, you could use the following regex:

```
expression = '"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}","[^"]*"'
```

Working example:

```
import re
my_str = '"FM 2222 RD / RIVER PLACE BLVD","0:",,"18:","00","2008-08-14","CRASH/LEAVING THE SCENE","30.39452568","(30.39452568-97.84551164)","-97.84551164","18:00:00","4","2008-08-14 18:00:00-06:00","20085043619"'
expression = '"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}","[^"]*"'
re.findall(expression, my_str)  # returns ['"2008-08-14","CRASH/LEAVING THE SCENE"']
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you provided looks like a line from a csv file and another option is to use Pythons [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Since I don't know if you have a file or list full of these strings, this example shows how you could take this single string and read it into [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) using [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io%20stringio#io.StringIO) (Python 3.6.4)

```
In[2]: s = '"FM 2222 RD / RIVER PLACE BLVD","0:",,"18:","00","2008-08-14","CRASH/LEAVING THE SCENE","30.39452568","(30.39452568-97.84551164)","-97.84551164","18:00:00","4","2008-08-14 18:00:00-06:00","20085043619"'
  ...: 
In[3]: import csv
  ...: import io
  ...: 
  ...: reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(s))
  ...: for line in reader:
  ...:     address, a, b, c, d, date, msg, *stuff = line
  ...:     print(date)
  ...:     print(msg)
  ...: 
2008-08-14
CRASH/LEAVING THE SCENE
```

If you had the actual csv file with the header, you could use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and then do something like `print(line['date'])` (assuming the key was 'date').